# How to debug ansible for general YAML syntax error without details to file and most likely unrelated to playbook itself?

Tags: debugging, ansible, syntax-error, yaml

I have refactored a huge playbook that includes other. I only changed the integration of `files/*` that get copied to the remote machines, i.e. changing from symlinks to real files etc. After that the playbook is not running anymore with no details for the error, only

`$ ansible-playbook site.yml -i production.inv --limit build.local --ask-vault-pass --check -vvvvv
Using /home/XY/.ansible.cfg as config file
Vault password:
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.`

Before the refactoring I see `statically included: common/tasks/ubuntu-fix.yml` output lines and if I manually add an error there, I get details like `The error appears to have been in 'common/tasks/install.yml': line 3, column 9, but may` also after the first file is included successfully. I conclude that the error happens before the first include, however the playbook itself is not changed and works in another folder with the old way of including files via symlink.

How can I debug in which file ansible fails?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was also a symlink, but to a yaml file in this case. In the other folder this symlink was correct. In the new version the symlink was broken and read in as physical binary file with the content

`!<symlink>�workspace/dev.yml%`

Why can't ansible help with showing that the inclusion of this file didn't work, i.e. to keep the general part of the question open how to debug such issues?